# Auth.changePassword throws 'incorrect username or password'

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, change-password

I am using react native and AWS for my backend. I am trying to add a feature that allows users to be able to change their password after they have logged into the app. I believe I should be able to do this using the Auth.changePassword function ([AWS doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#forgot-password)). For some reason, I am getting an error that the username or password is incorrect.

When testing, the user returns a CognitoUser, the oldPassword is definitely correct, and the newPassword throws errors if it does not meet the character settings. I am lost as to what the issue could be. Should I also be using completeChangePassword in conjunction?

```
import React from 'react';

import {Auth} from '@aws-amplify/auth';

export default class ChangePassword extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            oldPassword: '',
            newPassword: '',
        };
    }

    handleChangePassword = async () => {

        const { oldPassword, newPassword } = this.state;

        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(user => {
            return Auth.changePassword(user, oldPassword, newPassword)
            })
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .then(user => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home'))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
            
    }

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.text_header}>Change Password</Text>
            </View>
            <Animatable.View
                animation='bounceInUp'
                style={styles.footer}
            >
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Old Password</Text>
                <View style={styles.action}>
                    <Feather
                        name='lock'
                        color='#05375a'
                        size={20}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder='Enter old password'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        autoCapitalize='none'
                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ oldPassword: val })}
                    />
                </View>

                <Text style={styles.text_footer}>New Password</Text>
                <View style={styles.action}>
                    <Feather
                        name='lock'
                        color='#05375a'
                        size={20}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder='Enter new password'
                        style={styles.textInput}
                        autoCapitalize='none'
                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ newPassword: val })}
                    />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.signIn}
                        onPress={this.handleChangePassword}
                    >
                    <LinearGradient
                        colors={['#55B142', '#155843']}
                        style={styles.signIn}
                    >
                        <Text style={[ styles.textSign, { color: '#fff' }]}>Submit</Text>
                    </LinearGradient>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', paddingTop: 5 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('EditProfile')}
                            style={[styles.signUp, {
                                //borderColor: '#155843',
                                //borderWidth: 1,
                                marginTop: 15,
                            }]}
                        >
                            <Text style={[styles.textSign, {
                                color: '#155843'
                            }]}>Go Back</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
            </View>        
            </View>
            </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the account that was logged in wasn't verified which is why it would reject the email address.